# Cannot connect to android device from arch

Tags: android, archlinux

I am trying to push software to my phone from android studio but something very strange is happening. My Samsung S7 is detected under usb devices but not under android devices and there are 6 "ghost" android devices that are not in the usb devices list but show up in adb, all the "ghost" devices are listed as api level 1 and are unaccessable and i cannot connect to my phone, also my phone has usb debugging enabled, is in mtp mode and i have all the adb stuff and mtpfs and jmtpfs installed on my computer

Edit: Also when I connect my phone to my laptop my phone says `The connected device is unable to access data on this device. Reconnect the USB device and try again`

Edit 2: I added some udev rules and now the ghost devices have dissapeared but my device is still not accessable

Edit 3: I can access the files on my phone through MTP but adb still does not recognize it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the connection type in your phone for example from Media Device (MTP) to Camera (PTP). I had the same issue with my Galaxy S8 and changing the connection type fixed it.